# Explode a session variable in PHP always shows "Array"

Tags: php, session-variables

I try to explode the session variable named `"Name"` to get only the first name of the user.

However, when I try to `echo` it, the result is always `"Array"`.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
echo explode(" ", $_SESSION['name']);
```

Result is:  `Array`

I even tried to store the `$_SESSION['Name']` in a variable and explode that variable instead and got the same result.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't echo an array.  You can only echo strings.  `$names = explode(" ", $_SESSION['name']);  echo $names[0];`.

Comment: `explode()` always returns an array (as it clearly states in the manual), so why are you surprised that this is happening?

Comment: The result of [explode](http://us2.php.net/explode) is an array - what were you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
$tempVar = explode(" ", $_SESSION['name']);
echo $tempVar[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

`explode()` returns an array.  You need to access it by index or assign them to individual variables:

```
$names = explode(" ", $_SESSION['name']);
echo $names[0];
```

Or:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(" ", $_SESSION['name']);
echo $first;
```